# Do women have to be quiet?

Tags: women

I heard that it was stated in The Bible that "women must be SILENT in a Church building, etc." Does such a scripture exist and is it so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because verse request questions are not allowed anymore.

Comment: Looks like you didn't even try [Google](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?hl=en&gws_rd=cr&ei=9GVJVeLLDuTlmAXe44GwAw#hl=en&q=women+must+be+SILENT+in+a+Church+building).

Comment: why aren't verse request questions allowed?

Answer (score 3):

**Do women have to be quiet?**

> 1 Corinthians 14:34-35  Let your women keep silence in the churches:
>   for it is not permitted unto them to speak; but they are commanded to
>   be under obedience, as also saith the law.   And if they will learn
>   any thing, let them ask their husbands at home: for it is a shame for
>   women to speak in the church.

The context of the verse is Paul telling them that their church service is too chaotic. In particular he has been telling them that their use of spiritual gifts has not been orderly. Almost as an aside, he addresses the disorder brought about by women.

Today this does not apply so much because both men and women are silent in the more common lecture style of preaching in churches today. By implication the verses to the Corinthians show that their meetings had people asking questions.

Many people have taken the words to women to remain silent and ask their husbands at home as a big put down. However, you can make a case that men are being rebuked for not acting as teachers in their own homes and not being interested enough to answer their wives questions.

The "shame" may not be on women but on their husbands for being negligent.

Comment: I'm repeating this to emphasize it.  **The context of the verse is Paul telling them that their church service is too chaotic. In particular he has been telling them that their use of spiritual gifts has not been orderly. Almost as an aside, he addresses the disorder brought about by women.**  See verse 33:"for God is not a God of confusion but of peace, as in all the churches of the saints."

Answer (score 1):

Yes such a scripture exists, and it was so, at least for the women in Corinth and surrounding regions during the first century:

> "Let your women keep silence in the churches: for it is not permitted
>   unto them to speak; but *they are commanded* to be under obedience, as
>   also saith the law." [(1 Corinthians 14:34 KJV)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-cor/14.34?lang=eng#33)

The Greek word ὑποτασσέσθωσαν is translated "to be in submission", in Corinth, which is just West of Athens in Greece, it was apparently the law that women be submissive to the men.

One interpretation of this scripture is that Paul was specifically referring to women *ruling* in church meetings. It has been suggested that it is possible that Paul was trying to correct a situation in which some Corinthian women were either being disorderly during worship services or seeking to take the lead from priesthood leaders.<sup>[1](https://www.lds.org/manual/new-testament-student-manual/1-corinthians/chapter-39-1-corinthians-12-14.p120?lang=eng)</sup> This is evidenced in Paul's later epistle to Timothy while Paul was in captivity, and Timothy was in Ephesus, which is relatively close to Corinth:

> "Let the woman learn in silence with all subjection. But I suffer not a
>   woman to teach, nor to usurp authority over the man, but to be in
>   silence." [(1 Tim 2:11-12 KJV)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-tim/2.11-12?lang=eng#10)

---

<sup>1 [Chapter 39: 1 Corinthians 12–14 New Testament Student Manual, 2014](https://www.lds.org/manual/new-testament-student-manual/1-corinthians/chapter-39-1-corinthians-12-14.p120?lang=eng)</sup>

Comment: I've upvoted this, but it would be nice if you could find a source for "it has been suggested".